# how to compile c++ program in linux to produce windows executable?

Tags: c++, linux

I need to cross compile a C++ source code in Linux and run it on Windows. How can I compile it on Linux to produce `.exe` executable?

Is there any advantage for compiling in Linux to make Windows executable other than compiling it on Windows itself?

Comment: The easiest (by *far*) would be to use a virtual machine with Windows and compile natively there. Cross compiling is not simple, error prone and you can't debug the resulting binary without Windows anyway.

Comment: You'll need a compiler that is capable of building for Windows, as well as the required library files that you'd need to link with. There are pre-built packages of "cross compilers" available that will do this, just search the web and follow the instructions, more or less. As to an advantage, depends on how you look at it. You'd most likely want to run your produced executable, which is difficult if you don't have a windows machine available.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Does compiling on linux provide any added advantage at compile time? Which could be the preferred choice?

Comment: You can look for cross compiler. 
In [Compile for Windows on Linux](http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/) the author describe a way do perform it.

Comment: You might need some Windows license to compile and link code for it. There could be legal issues if you don't legally own some Windows license. But I am not a lawyer.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch given that Microsoft makes [VS code for linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) I doubt that.

Comment: VS code is an editor (so is irrelevant). To link a Windows C++ program, you need DLLs for the C++ standard library (and for [lower level system stuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files) used by it, e.g. `KERNEL32.DLL`, `USER32.DLL`, etc). I believe there is some EULA on these. I leave you to check, because I never used Windows

Comment: @Caleth: Feel free to provide some *legal* way do download these DLLs without accepting any [EULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) to prove your claim.

Answer (score 1):

a virtual machine on VMware could be a Quick solution

Comment: more like a comment than a solution

Comment: Moreover he asked to compile on Linux. This provide a way to compile on windows by not installing it. Doesn't well fit the problem.

Comment: yes , it is my personal suggestion ;)